# I need help extracting a specific piece of text from a webpage

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to assign the 11101973 number in this html file to a variable but need a way of grabbing that number only without any of the extra information :

```
<div class="chooseSizeContainer" id="2SizeContainer" style="display:none;">
 <div class="chooseSizeLinkContainer active">
 <a id="US-13" href="javascript:void(0);"
 class="chooseSizeLink chooseSizeLinkActive"
 data-size="13"                                                 
 onclick="ProductDetails.changeSizeAffectedLinks(
 '11101973',
 '£ 135.95',
 '£ 135.95',
 '0',
 '£ 0.00saved!',
 '13',
 '13',
 '15',
 'false',
 'false',
 'false',
 'false',
 'unknown',
 'US-',
 '555088-015');">13</a>
 </div>
```

The page source is here if more info is needed : view-source:https://www.kickz.com/uk/jordan-basketball-retro-air-jordan-1-retro-high-og-black_varsity_red_sail_university_blue-107840036
Any help appreciated!

Comment: Please provide the code you're using and examples of what you've attempted.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

beautifulsoup is for parsing html element not javascript variable. There are few javascript parser out there but for simple task I prefer `Regex`

```
import requests, re

page = requests.get(url).text
theNumber = re.search(r'collectAskInput\((\d+)).group(1)
print(theNumber)
# 11101973
```

it search the number in

```
onclick="return ProductDetails.collectAskInput(11101973)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's in the source as a script tag, which you can pull out the string that's in the form of a dictionary.

```
import requests
import bs4
import json

url = 'https://www.kickz.com/uk/jordan-basketball-retro-air-jordan-1-retro-high-og-black_varsity_red_sail_university_blue-107840036'

response = requests.get(url)

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

scripts = soup.find_all('script')

jsonObj = None
for script in scripts:
    if 'ec:addProduct' in script.text:
        jsonStr = script.text

        jsonStr = jsonStr.split("ga('ec:addProduct',")[1]
        jsonStr = jsonStr.split(");")[-4]
        jsonStr = jsonStr.replace("'", '"')

        jsonObj = json.loads(jsonStr)

id_var = jsonObj['id']    
print (id_var)
```

**Output:**

```
print (id_var)
107840036
```